# In google plus how to get the userId while the authentication code is given and google plus sign up button(php)

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
require_once '/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_HttpRequest.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
 $client->setClientId('123236981117-cr7rt023bpg3n9b698pdqhk0353hpjgi.apps.googleusercontent.com');
 $client->setClientSecret('');
 $client->setRedirectUri('');
 $client->setDeveloperKey('');


$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

// Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
     $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
 // Verify the token

  $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
          $token->access_token;
  $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);


  $tokenInfo = json_decode(
      $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());

  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

        // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
  // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php


  $url = filter_var($me['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

  $birth = filter_var($user['birthday'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

  $img = filter_var($me['image']['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

  $name = filter_var($me['displayName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

  $personMarkup = "<a rel='me' href='$url'>$name</a><div><img src='$img'></div>";

  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);


  $activityMarkup = '';
  foreach($activities['items'] as $activity) {
    // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
    // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
    $url = filter_var($activity['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $title = filter_var($activity['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $content = filter_var($activity['object']['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    $activityMarkup .= "<div class='activity'><a href='$url'>$title</a><div>$content</div></div>";
  }


  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Google+ Sample App</h1></header>
<div class="box">

<?php if(isset($personMarkup)): ?>
<div class="me"><?php print $personMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if(isset($activityMarkup)): ?>
<div class="activities">Your Activities: <?php print $activityMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
  if(isset($authUrl)) {
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
   print "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
  }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey every one by using this code i am getting the user's information and user's activites.
I am also verifing the token. But the problem is i do not know how to get google+ userID if the authentication code is given to me.so i want to do the following thing

If there was an error in the token info, abort.

And i want to add the google plus sign up button also in to my appliaction.

Please Somebody help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's UserID will be one of the elements returned in $me. You can compare this with the UserID that the client side gets (and passes to the server) to verify that the client isn't trying to lie to the server about who it is.